# Find first second third...heather values and cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i need help to resolv a problem in excel. i have a sheet that contains some distribution relative to a cell value (image1)[image]

And i need to have this information in a table like this one (image2)[image]

i have manage to get all the values in a new sheet repeated the necessary number of times as seen in image 2, but i cant find a whay to retrieve the headers for those values (i only can retrieve automaticly the first non zero value header, not the others)

can anyone help me in this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can unpivot the data https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUXJLzqlEPk or https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Comment: The problem is that i have to do this every month and i woud like to construct an excell file where i only have to copy paste the values to the sheet and it automaticly gives me these information

Answer (score 0):

I took this challenge. Give it a try and see if it's what you want. **It does not print header values**.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PivotData()

Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

With ActiveSheet

    'Count the number of rows needed
    Dim countRange As Range
    Set countRange = Range("D2", .Cells(.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row, .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column))
    Dim rCount As Long
    rCount = wf.Count(countRange)

    'Loop through countRange and fill array
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim arr(rCount - 1, 2) As Variant
    For Each r In countRange
        If r > 0 Then
            arr(i, 0) = .Cells(r.Row, 1).Value
            arr(i, 1) = .Cells(1, r.Column).Value
            arr(i, 2) = .Cells(r.Row, r.Column).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r

    'Print array back to the worksheet 3 rows after the last used row
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0).Resize(rCount, 3) = arr
End With

End Sub
```

As always, there could be a better way. But I believe this will work for you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help Brian, i was hoping that ihere is a way that i could do it exclusivly with formulas, but i will give your help a try :)